# Access method of class above

Tags: scala

How can I use the isEmpty of class A in Class B?

```
Class A{
  def isEmpty = ...

  Class B{
    def isEmpty = ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
class A {
  outer =>

  def isEmpty = ...
  class B {
    def isEmpty = outer.isEmpty
  }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
class A {
  def isEmpty = ...
  class B {
    def isEmpty = A.this.isEmpty
  }
}
```